# How to set status of a check box in Oracle Apex using PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I set a value of a check box after submit?

I clicked the check box and when I click in the submit button, it deselects.

Comment: Is this a page item of type Checkbox, or a checkbox in a report region?

Comment: Its a page item of type Checkbox. If you go here i have an example of my problem [link](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=17236:555) if you want change anything you can do it with this user and password  user/123qweASD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the example you linked to in a comment above, I think your checkbox item is not set up correctly.  Looking at the URL in the browser after checking the checkbox and pressing the Apply button I see:

```
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=17236:555:3681260444833458::NO::P555_CHECK:
```

That explicitly sets the values of the checkbox item to NULL, which is normally the unchecked value.  As an experiment I changed the URL to:

```
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=17236:555:3681260444833458::NO::P555_CHECK:Y
```

The page reloaded with two checkboxes!:

[image: two checkboxes]

So how is your checkbox item defined?  It should be defined something like this:
[image]

i.e.

- the number of checkbox columns should be 1
- "display extra values" and "display null values" should both be set to No
- the list of values should only specify the checked value (I have used 'Y').  This can be done via a named LOV rather than the way I have done it.

Also, you don't want to reset P555_CHECK to null in the page branch.

Comment: Ok, nice answer. Tanks for your help @Tony Andrews

Comment: @Tony Andrews Hi, what you told me worked great but when doing the apply the chart is not designed and should be. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I saw that the chart on your page failed to load, but I don't know why.  You may want to start a new question for this.

Comment: Ok i will do it. Can you help me in page 555 i was tring to see what was wrong in the load of the chart and now i dont know why i can't put your example of the Y checkbox working again. Can you see what i'm doing wrong? Tanks

Comment: When you press Apply your branch is resetting P555_CHECK to null, i.e. unchecked - as per my answer

Comment: Tanks for your help, i solve the problem of the chart not loading